# How can I get drag and drop box to reset position?

Tags: javascript, html

Before I start here is the jsFiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/SSxdB/5/

And the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        #dragBox {width:336px; height:221px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
    </style>
    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        if (data == "drag1")
        {
            foodOne();
        }
        if (data == "drag2")
        {
            foodTwo();
        }
    }

    function foodOne()
    {
        alert("You choose Food One");
    }

    function foodTwo()
    {
        alert("You choose Food Two");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#333333">
<div div align="center">
    <img id="drag1" src="foodOne.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="221">
    <img id="drag2" src="foodTwo.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="221">
    <br><br>
    <div id="dragBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two images (images are not showing in the jsFiddle since link is local but you get the idea) and a box where I can drag them.  The problem is when I drag one image into the box that image is no longer there and when I drag the 2nd image it sort of collapses with the drop box and it moves out of its original position.

I'm trying to make it so that when user drags in the image, that image is not removed from the top and when the second image is moved in it does the same thing and also the drop box always stays in the same position when ever the image is dragged in.

If anyone can help me with this that would be great!

Comment: Nick, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, would you by any chance be wanting to allow both images to be dragged in, but only one instance of each?

Comment: ok, last update should do the trick =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloneNode to duplicate the image node, and append that to the image box. That way the original image node stays intact:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var draggedOrNewNodeId = "dragged-"+data;
    var theNode = document.getElementById(data);
    var draggedNode = document.getElementById(draggedOrNewNodeId);
    if (draggedNode != null) { ev.target.removeChild(draggedNode); }
    var nodeCopy = theNode.cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = draggedOrNewNodeId;
    nodeCopy.setAttribute("class", "dragged");
    nodeCopy.setAttribute("draggable", "false")
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);

    if (data == "drag1") {
        foodOne();
    }
    if (data == "drag2") {
        foodTwo();
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/raad/SSxdB/15/

Tested on Firefox 19.0 and Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m, both on Windows 7
I don't see your collapsing box problem though.

**Edit**

The updated code now clones the dragged node and assigns it a new id, which can be used to remove it when a new node is dragged in, plus allows only one instance of each node to be dragged in, and disables drag on the dragged nodes (this is easily removed) to prevent further dragging from polluting the container.

Comment: This helps, but I'm trying to get it so that only one image is displayed in the box when dropped and when I drag the second image that image is displayed and so on...  Right now its appending every image dropped, but I need it to show only one image at a time.  Is this possible?

Comment: Could I set node to empty after each time it executes?

Comment: With the update it only works on the first drag but after that nothing is happening when I drag any of the images.  I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: @Nick - I've updated my answer, so hopefully it should meet what you need.